# Changing a property of an object from GameViewController.swift in GameScene.swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm new to Swift, so sorry if this seems like an obvious question.

I'm trying to write a game in Swift, and I have designed a label and a play button in the storyboard.

[image: Main.storyboard]

I've added references to these objects in the *GameViewController.swift* file as seen here:

```
// MARK: Objects
@IBOutlet var gameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var playButton: UIImageView!

// MARK: Actions

@IBAction func playButtonTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        GameScene().gameStart()
}
```

This belongs to the GameViewController class: `class GameViewController: UIViewController`.

However, the main game itself takes place in *GameScene.swift*. This involves me having to hide the label and image as soon as the game starts. I'm unsure how to set the properties for these objects to hide, since if I did the following in *GameScene.swift*:

```
GameViewController().playButton.hidden = true
```

...the game crashes with a fatal error. The error says: *fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*.

Does anyone have a suggestion for this problem? Any help is much appreciated. Sorry if the information was difficult to understand.

Cheers.

Comment: You can add a property to GameScene class, to keep a reference to the GameViewController that will be managing that GameScene. And then do gameVC.gameLabel.hidden = true. If you want a pretty good solution you can add a protocol and declare methods for gameDidStart() and son on, and let the GameScene delegate be your GameViewController. Hope it helps

Comment: did you miss the part where he said he's new to Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of 'GameViewController()`, but you want you want use your already existent one. If you only want to create one`GameViewController`, which is probably the case, you could use a static instance variable.

In `GameViewController`, put:

```
static var instance: GameViewController!
```

In it's `viewDidLoad()`, put:

```
GameViewController.instance = self
```

Finally, in your `GameScene`, switch `GameViewController()` with `GameViewController.instance`.

Comment: I've done this, but I'm now experiencing crashes in another section of my code. In one of my functions my code crashes when I get to `randomX = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame)-700))+351)`. I've found out that `CGRectGetWidth(self.frame)` gives me 1.0 instead of 1024.0. I know this sounds very noob-ish of me, but do you know why this is? Here's the functions that are ran: [link](http://pastebin.com/VaiJ3T2E). Any ideas?

Comment: @KaiSilverthorne Try `self.frame` should be used in the ViewController, but you are using it in the scene. Try either `GVC.frame.width` or `self.size.width`.

Comment: What I did was do the "static var" for GameScene as well, and got the frame size from the GameScene and saved it as a variable. I then passed these sizes on to the functions as arguments. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome; I had a similar issue when I started SpriteKit!